# Pandas df.ix not replacing

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
df1_9

       date store_nbr   item_nbr    units   station_nbr tavg    preciptotal
8   2012-01-01  1         9          29          1        42      0.05
119 2012-01-02  1         9          60          1        41      0.01
...
452 2012-01-05  1         9          16          1        32      0.00
563 2012-01-06  1         9          12          1        36       T
```

I want to replace the 'T' in the preciptotal column with the value .01.

```
df1_9.ix[df1_9.preciptotal == 'T', 'preciptotal'] = 0.01
```

I wrote this code, but for some reason it is not working. I have been staring at this for a while, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the value really is 'T' and there are no whitespaces? for instance what does `df1_9[df1_9.preciptotal == 'T'`]` show?

Comment: Ah yes you are right, no rows are returned when I do 'df1_9[df1_9.preciptotal == 'T']'. How can I figure out what is stored if it is not just 'T'

Comment: you can do eg `df1_9.preciptotal.unique()`